# Redirecting HTTPS site to non-www in ASP.NET Core application on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I don't want to change my code
are there any solution for Redirecting HTTPS site to non-www in ASP.NET Core application via IIS?
are there any solution on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your web.config using the IIS URL Rewrite module:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url="(.*)" /> 
        <conditions> 
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions> 
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
      </rule> 
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If using ASP.NET Core 2.1 you can use [UseHttpsRedirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.httpspolicybuilderextensions.usehttpsredirection) middleware.

Comment: I add this to web.config it give 500 - Internal server error.
and there is not rewrite module here,IIS :  http://i.hizliresim.com/pnPypq.png

Comment: You'll need to install [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).